# Python Pandas Dataframe pull column value/index down by one

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am using a pandas DataFrame and I would like to pull one column value/index down by one. So the list Dataframe Length will be one less. Just like this in my example image:

[image: DataFrame before -> after]

The new DataFrame should be `id` 2-5, but of course re-index after the manipulation to 1-4. There are more than just `name` and `place` rows.

How can I quickly manipulate the DataFrame like this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.1/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) the name column and then take a slice using [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc):

```
In [55]:   
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(1,6), 'name':['john', 'bla', 'tim','walter','john'], 'place':['new york','miami','paris','rome','sydney']})
df

Out[55]:

   id    name     place
0   1    john  new york
1   2     bla     miami
2   3     tim     paris
3   4  walter      rome
4   5    john    sydney

In [56]:    
df['name'] = df['name'].shift(-1)
df = df.iloc[:-1]
df

Out[56]:

   id    name     place
0   1     bla  new york
1   2     tim     miami
2   3  walter     paris
3   4    john      rome
```

If your 'id' column is your index the above still works:

```
In [62]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john', 'bla', 'tim','walter','john'], 'place':['new york','miami','paris','rome','sydney']},index=np.arange(1,6))    
df.index.name = 'id'
df

Out[62]:

      name     place
id                  
1     john  new york
2      bla     miami
3      tim     paris
4   walter      rome
5     john    sydney

In [63]:   
df['name'] = df['name'].shift(-1)
df = df.iloc[:-1]
df

Out[63]:

      name     place
id                  
1      bla  new york
2      tim     miami
3   walter     paris
4     john      rome
```